# How to use app delegate xcode

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, delegates

how do you call the app delegate methods in the view controller. i want to save my app data before the application terminates. in another app ive created an instance of the delegate and a variable inside it, so every few seconds it checks the delegate if this is true (it sets it to true when the application will resign active) but this doesn't seem the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: oh, and can you just add the UIApplicationDelegate to the controller?????

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save your app data before the application terminates,hen save your data in `applicationWillTerminate` method of application life cycle.

there is no need to more one delegate, apple already providing you this facility then why you are creating new one. just write your code in `applicationWillTerminate` method

just reference your viewController from appdelegate & you can call to method in which you want to processing save data.

Comment: i the data are subclasses of uiimageview and i save the properties of them.

Comment: so theres no way of calling an instance method of the view controller from the delegate?

Comment: @user1726450 In order to save data that's accessible from the view controller in your app delegate's implementation of `applicationWillTerminate:`, you just need to have a reference to your view controller in your app delegate.  If you had a property `viewController` on your app delegate, then in `applicationWillTerminate:` you could write `[self.viewController saveTheData]`.

Comment: i see, but i'm using storyboard, so how do i change it so that app delegate is the first file loaded

Comment: also  can you look at my comment above the original post